# Can converting structure elements to const-reference save some overhead?

Tags: c++

**Scenario,**

I have a trace file having thousands of 'Entries'(I call them 'tick').
Each 'Entry' contains several lines of information. 
There are two types of information(location data and multicast data) so each line is either about 'location' or 'multicast'.

**Goal:**
My goal is to store them into my data structure efficiently:

**Implementation:**

for storing information of each entry, I have :

```
//////////////////
struct multicast_data{
//... integers, vectors of integers, string etc.
}
std::list<multicast_data> multicasts;
///////////////////////
struct AgentLocation{
 //... integers, operator overload etc.
};
std::set<AgentLocation> agentsLocation;
////////////////////////
```

Next, I want to store the entries in a queue, So I first bundle them in another structure like this:

```
struct tickDataBundle{
        const std::list<multicast_data> & multicasts;
        const std::set<AgentLocation> & agentsLocation;
        tickDataBundle(const std::list<multicast_data> &multicasts,
                const std::set<AgentLocation> &agentsLocation):
                    multicasts(multicasts),
                    agentsLocation(agentsLocation){}
    };
```

then I put them into a queue:

```
MessageQueue<tickDataBundle> m_processed_data;
```

**Questions:**

1. My confusion is, the containers(list and set) in `tickDataBundle` are created and populated in the scope of some method, and naturally these containers are destroyed when the scope ends(no heap). So even returning the reference to these containers will create dangling reference. So I figured if,before the scope ends, I add the `const-reference` of these containers to `tickDataBundle` object, then push this object to the `MessageQueue` , I would have benefitted from the C++'s optimization to save the full containers from being destroyed and reduce some copying overhead. was this a correct and valid assumption?
2. why cant't I save a const-reference of `tickDataBundle` in the above queue?
   (`MessageQueue<const tickDataBundle&> m_processed_data;` generates error)

thank you

**UPDATE: this part is JUST FOR YOUR REFERENCE**
I am copying 
the structure of my `MessageQueue` and
the error I will get if I declare `MessageQueue<const tickDataBundle&> m_processed_data;`

```
template<class T>
class MessageQueue {
    std::queue<T> messageList;
    boost::shared_mutex mutex;
public:
    MessageQueue();
    virtual ~MessageQueue();
    bool ReadMessage();
    void post(T message);
    bool pop(T&);
    void clear();
    int size();
};
```

error:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/deque:64:0,
                     from /usr/include/c++/4.8/queue:60,
                     from ./ns3/drop-tail-queue.h:22,
                     from ./ns3/network-module.h:24,
                     from ../src/simmobility/examples/simmobility-RR-baseline.cc:2:
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_deque.h: In instantiation of ‘class std::_Deque_base<const sim_mob::RoadRunnerBaseLine::tickDataBundle&, std::allocator<const sim_mob::RoadRunnerBaseLine::tickDataBundle&> >’:
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_deque.h:730:11:   required from ‘class std::deque<const sim_mob::RoadRunnerBaseLine::tickDataBundle&, std::allocator<const sim_mob::RoadRunnerBaseLine::tickDataBundle&> >’
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_queue.h:96:46:   required from ‘class std::queue<const sim_mob::RoadRunnerBaseLine::tickDataBundle&, std::deque<const sim_mob::RoadRunnerBaseLine::tickDataBundle&, std::allocator<const sim_mob::RoadRunnerBaseLine::tickDataBundle&> > >’
    ./ns3/smb_message_queue.h:18:16:   required from ‘class sim_mob::MessageQueue<const sim_mob::RoadRunnerBaseLine::tickDataBundle&>’
    ./ns3/smb_roadrunner_baseline.h:87:47:   required from here
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_deque.h:448:60: error: forming pointer to reference type ‘const sim_mob::RoadRunnerBaseLine::tickDataBundle&’
           typedef _Deque_iterator<_Tp, _Tp&, _Tp*>             iterator;
                                                                ^
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_deque.h:449:60: error: forming pointer to reference type ‘const sim_mob::RoadRunnerBaseLine::tickDataBundle&’
           typedef _Deque_iterator<_Tp, const _Tp&, const _Tp*> const_iterator;
                                                                ^
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_deque.h:488:61: error: forming pointer to reference type ‘const sim_mob::RoadRunnerBaseLine::tickDataBundle&’
           typedef typename _Alloc::template rebind<_Tp*>::other _Map_alloc_type;
    AND THE ERROR CONTINUES...
```

Comment: You should show the error message and the definition (or type) of `MessageQueue`.  It may be due to a copy-constructor somewhere.  I don't see why you would want to store the `tickDataBundle` as a reference.  It's a tiny structure.  You would have to have it stored elsewhere anyway, in order to keep a reference in your `MessageQueue`.

Comment: By the way, if you're concerned about efficiency you should use `std::vector` or `std::deque` instead of `std::list`

Comment: @paddy based on your first comment, since `tickDataBundle` is tiny, it wouldn't matter much to try to stor a reference into the queue. How about tickDataBundle elements? except for replacing the std::list, does declaring the elements as const-reference makes it any efficient? what if I just declare them as reference? will it make any difference with respect to efficiency?

Comment: @paddy about using `std::vector` instead of `std::list`: the trace file is 25GB!, the vector may need to grow many times, and based of the vector operation, looking for a bigger memory chunk to store vector's continuous elements may increase the overhead. Don't you think so? (i don't know about std::queue yet)

Comment: Regarding your first comment, I'm not sure if you understand references.  A reference must point at something and then the reference itself also takes storage (think *pointers*, but not quite the same).  Regarding your second comment, you use a `std::deque` for exactly this reason, or you write a custom allocator for `std::list` to use a memory pool.

Comment: Also....  Since we seem to be doing two comments at a time, here's another comment about your vector growing.  How large would each vector inside a `tickDataBundle` get?  Vector sizes increase such with a linear amortized time complexity.  The downside to this is that a vector might reserve just under twice the amount of memory that is required to store the elements.  Because you are pumping these into a queue, I suspect that you handle only one vector at a time, so you could in fact resize the vector back down to the required size before putting it in the queue.

Comment: Ok, i will look into resizing the vector before pushing it. Thanks. Still, you haven't given me a yes/no answer to my first question.I updated the question to a more clear one. Appreciate if you have a look at it. Thanks again.

Comment: You did not post any code that shows how you are trying to use this, so that we could explain the error better.  We can only speculate.  I think that you might have misunderstood what references are and how they are used.  To answer your question about whether using a reference is more "efficient", then no it's not.  If you store the object, it uses a bunch of memory.  If you store a reference to the object, you still have to store the *target* of those references somewhere, so you need extra memory for the references.  De-referencing them later costs CPU time for the additional memory access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*1. I figured if I make const-reference if the elements in the tickDataBundle, it will reduce some copying overhead. was this a correct and valid assumption?*

The answer is yes. All copy of `tickDataBundle` objects only own the const reference of `multicasts` and `agentsLocation`, not coping real data in them.

*2. why cant't I save a const-reference of tickDataBundle in the above queue? (MessageQueue m_processed_data; generates error)*

The const reference must be assigned at the object construct time point. You can use **const pointer** as **const reference**, like this:

```
MessageQueue<const tickDataBundle*> m_processed_data;
```

Comment: just to make sure about the first question: my confusion is, the containers(list and set) are created and populated in the `scope` of some method, and naturally these containers are destroyed when the scope ends(no heap).So even returning the reference to these containers will create reference dangling. So I figured if,before the scope ends, I add the const-ref of these containers to `tickDataBundle` object, then push this `object to the `MessageQueue` , I would have used the C++'s optimization and save the full containers from being destroyed. So again, was this a correct assumption?

Comment: This is a NOT correct assumption. Any objects (including containers like list and set) in C++ must be destroyed beyond the life cycle, whether if these objects are referenced or pointed. You can define these containers as static or global variable which is destroyed at the process end point.